# tkinter Python Save User input for future use

Tags: python

I'm trying to develop an application where you can send emails. But I want to be able to save the messages, sender email and receiver email so they can just resend the email again without inputting the same message and email again.

I was able to create the email sending application, but I dont know how to save it so if I close the program, I can just send the same message again.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
open("email.txt","wb") as f:
    f.write(my_email_message)
```

then just load it and resend it from `email.txt` i guess ...

Answer (score 0):

If they've already 'sent' the email before closing then you can temporarily save the input as a variable.

```
root=Tk()
Label(root, text = "Enter email: ").grid(row = 0, sticky = W)
email.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
email=Entry(root)
```

You could then append or write the variable to a separate .txt file.

```
file=open.("file.txt", "a")
file.write(email)
file.close()
```